# How to fetch the sentence or portion,if a specific word is present in it

Tags: java, solr

For my application i need to retrieve the sentence or a portion of the sentence(if the sentence length is large) from a paragraph where a specific keyword is present.

condition:
if keyword is:hello world star
The sentence should contain either one of the word(ie.hello,world or star) or "hello world star".

Thanks.

Comment: I have implemented a logic in such a way if one word is passed ie.if "java" is passed ,it returns sentence with java.

Comment: Ok so add the code that you have tried. You will get more results and assistance if you show that you actually put forth some effort.

Comment: Sorry,I don't have the code now.sure I can provide the code tomorrow as I am not at my system.

Answer (score 0):

That is quite simple I guess . Suppose you have a field title in your index , then query like q=title:(hello world star) . Keeping the words inside the parenthesis does the trick . This will 100℅ work . Let me know if that helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried the above solution.Its not working.

Comment: Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^.!?,;]*("+key+")[^.?!;]*[.?,!]");
I am using the above code.If i am querying the index as -java Solr,above code takes "java solr" as one string and tries to match,but not java and Solr separately.

Comment: I think you need to change your field Type to make my solution work . What is the fieldType are you using for this field in schema.xml .

Comment: field type is content.I changed the field type too.
q=content:(java solr).
Is what I have wrote correct.